# Why the browser doesn't show any html code?

Tags: html, browser

When I write this code in the `index.php`, the result will be a blank pager *(white page)*:

```html
<html>
     <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>mytitle</title>
      <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/myweb/img/favicon.png">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/myweb/css/index.css">
     </head>
     <body>
      sometext 
     </body>
    </html>
```

I have to see `sometext` in the page, right? But I don't see anything. Noted that the title will be `mytitle`. Ok what's wrong? why I don't see anything?

Also when I run this:
[image]
the result is still a blank page. basically I have to see `test` in the result part, right? So what's the problem?

Comment: Works in the snippet editor

Comment: … if you click "Run" at least.

Comment: @JohnConde no it [doesn't work](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OgCPO.png)

Comment: @Quentin I have 1k rep, so trust me, I clicked "Run" before asking.

Comment: @stack — https://www.evernote.com/l/AAOf0eGZw7FHRquTkHFVHxHu1gW7iUQifaI

Comment: @Quentin Odd ...! then I really do not know what should I say.

Comment: Working as intended. http://i.imgur.com/YcpvOZA.png

Comment: Just for kicks, what's in your index.css that could affect your live page (but wouldn't load in the snippet)?

Answer (score -1):

If it is a `index.html` (normal html file) then browser would displayed the text. But you have created a `index.php` file, which php needs to parse and output. Try this,

```
<?php
echo '<p>here comes the html markup</p>';
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Completely wrong. Anything outside `<?php` and `?>` will be passed straight through to the HTTP response.